# Not getting email address with friend list

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I using this code for getting friends list from Facebook using access token. This token have previlage to access the email details.

```
$context = stream_context_create(array(
'http' => array(
'ignore_errors'=>true,
'method'=>'GET'

 )
 ));

 $token = 'access token';

 $response = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?    access_token=".$token, false, $context));

echo "<pre>";
print_r($response);
die();
```

But i got out put like this

```
      stdClass Object
     (
      [data] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [name] => name 1
                [id] => id1
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [name] => name 2
                [id] => id 2
            ))
    )
```

How i get Email address with this array. Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you cant get the email id of friends using the Facebook Graph API its not allowed.

Check the documentation here

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/email-permissions/

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/friendlist/

In addition you can try out the graph explorer to see if you are able to get the friends email id, you can see that its not returning the email id.

Answer (score 0):

> $response =
> json_decode(file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=".$token,
> false, $context), true);

https://www.php.net/json_decode

Answer (score 0):

you need to ask the user for the email perms before try to recive it